# SQL Query TA BioStar

Tags: sql, database

i have the  Query to show TA values and the result will be show as below

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(second, dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime, '19700101 00:00:00'),103) as [date] ,left(convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(second, dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime, '19700101 00:00:00'),108),5) as [time],
CASE WHEN dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.[nReaderIdn] in(539577044) THEN 'F1' WHEN dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.[nReaderIdn] in(539577051) THEN 'F2' END AS FunctionKey,TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.sFieldValue8 as EMPLOYEEID
FROM dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG INNER JOIN dbo.TB_USER ON dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nUserID = dbo.TB_USER.sUserID INNER JOIN dbo.TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO ON dbo.TB_USER.nUserIdn = dbo.TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.nUserIdn
where nDateTime > datediff(second, '19700101 00:00:00', DATEADD(DAY, -4, getdate())) and nDateTime < datediff(second, '19700101 00:00:00', getdate())


╔════════════╤═══════╤═════════════╤════════════╗
║ date       │ time  │ FunctionKey │ EMPLOYEEID ║
╠════════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪════════════╣
║ 21/02/2019 │ 08:37 AM │ F1          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 04:39 PM │ F2          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 04:56 PM │ F1          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 05:49 PM│ F2          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 05:53 PM │ F1          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 06:06 PM│ F2          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 01:26 PM│ F1          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 01:32 PM│F1          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 01:33 PM│ F2          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 01:45 PM│ F1          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 03:00 PM│ F2          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 04:38 PM│ F1          │ 19564      ║
╚════════════╧═══════╧═════════════╧════════════╝
```

the result shows all the attendance times even if there more than one time for the same user per day .

if any one can help i need ,to show only the min value F1 and the max value F2 per date,employee id

```
╔════════════╤═══════╤═════════════╤════════════╗
║ date       │ time  │ FunctionKey │ EMPLOYEEID ║
╠════════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪════════════╣
║ 21/02/2019 │ 08:37 AM│ F1          │ 19564      ║
╟────────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────╢
║ 21/02/2019 │ 06:06 PM│ F2          │ 19564      ║
╚════════════╧═══════╧═════════════╧════════════╝
```

Comment: Edit your question and (1) include the query in the question as *text*.  (2) Provide a database tag.  (3) Provide the results that you want *as a text table*.

Comment: Hi there. Your expected result seems to contradict your requirement. You stated that you want the min value for F1 but the value displayed in your result is the Max value of F1. Is it an error in your output or in your requirement ?

Comment: no but i forget to add AM, PM , the f1 is AM , f2 is PM . .

Comment: What data type is the `time` column?

Comment: left(convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(second, dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime, '19700101 00:00:00'),108),5) as [time],

Comment: What data type is the underlying column (`TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime`?) used to extract `time` from? Maybe you should add some sample data for clarity.

Comment: i added the query for reference

Answer (score 0):

in order to show the result at the same column, I made some changes,

```
SELECT EmployeeID,date,FunctionKey,
CASE when FunctionKey='F1' then min(time) else max(time) end as Final_Time
FROM [TA] group by date,EmployeeID,FunctionKey;
```

Here the result will show Min time value for F1 and max time value for F2 per EmployeeID, date at the same column, again I am not sure what time type you are using, maybe you can convert your current format to 24 hours format and then sort it.

Comment: thanks , but i need the min and max value in the same colum

Comment: no it not solved , i added the query above, and i need to show the min and max value in the same coloum

Answer (score 0):

You should use UNION here to get both results and when calculating MIN and MAX it should be on the original date/time column and not the converted string

Something like this but grossly simplified

```
SELECT CONVERT(...dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime...) AS [date], 
       CONVERT(..., MIN(dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime), ...) AS [Time], empId, 'F1'
WHERE funcKey = 'F1'
GROUP BY CONVERT(...dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime...), empId
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(...dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime...) AS [date], 
       CONVERT(..., MAX(dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime), ...) AS [Time], empId, 'F2'
WHERE funcKey = 'F2'
GROUP BY CONVERT(...dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime...), empId
```

Comment: yes its close , but the funckey is case , i canot group by . and it keep showing
Column 'dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @zaidhaj Since you are using funcKey in WHERE clause it can be hard coded in the SELECT and then it doesn't need to be part of the GROUP BY. Answer updated.

Comment: it work but the min and max values are incorrect , i change the format to be 
Min (convert(datetime,DATEADD(second, dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime, '19700101 00:00:00'),103) )

Comment: @zaidhaj I don't fully understand what you do in your CONVERT(...) but isn't `103` a  date only format? I thought MIN/MAX was based on on time

Comment: the ndatetime table value is ( 1541290539)  after converting it using the convert function the real value is (2018-11-04 00:15:39.000) 
this is why i have to convert

Comment: @zaidhaj Ok  but you want `108` to get the time part right?

Comment: i test it with 108 and it showing more than one value per date , not only the min,max value

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result what you expected after grouping by date. right?

Try it.

```sql
SELECT [date],left(convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(second, utc, '19700101 00:00:00'),108),5) as [time], FunctionKey,TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.sFieldValue8 as  EMPLOYEEID
  FROM (
        SELECT MMDDYYYY AS [date], nUserID, MIN(nDateTime) as utc , 'F1' AS FunctionKey
          FROM (

                SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(second, dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime, '19700101 00:00:00'),103) AS MMDDYYYY
                       , nUserID
                       , nDateTime
                  FROM dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG
                 WHERE nDateTime > datediff(second, '19700101 00:00:00', DATEADD(DAY, -4, getdate())) 
                       and nDateTime < datediff(second, '19700101 00:00:00', getdate())
                       and dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.[nReaderIdn] in(539577044) ) DATE_ADDED
         GROUP BY MMDDYYYY, nUserID
         UNION ALL
        SELECT MMDDYYYY AS [date], nUserID, MAX(nDateTime) as utc , 'F2' AS FunctionKey
          FROM (
                SELECT convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(second, dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.nDateTime, '19700101 00:00:00'),103) AS MMDDYYYY
                       , nUserID
                       , nDateTime
                  FROM dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG
                 WHERE nDateTime > datediff(second, '19700101 00:00:00', DATEADD(DAY, -4, getdate())) 
                       and nDateTime < datediff(second, '19700101 00:00:00', getdate())
                       and dbo.TB_EVENT_LOG.[nReaderIdn] in(539577051) ) DATE_ADDED
         GROUP BY MMDDYYYY, nUserID  ) TA_DATA
       INNER JOIN dbo.TB_USER ON TA_DATA.nUserID = dbo.TB_USER.sUserID 
       INNER JOIN dbo.TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO ON dbo.TB_USER.nUserIdn = dbo.TB_USER_CUSTOMINFO.nUserIdn
```